# Does a Super Noether Theorem exist?

Tags: symmetry, group-theory, supersymmetry, lie-algebra, noethers-theorem

I am wondering if an extension of [Noether theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) to [supergroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supergroup_%28physics%29) exists.
In particular the analogy with the usual case should be that supersymmmetries are in 1-to-1 correspondence to certain "currents" whose charge is the supersymmetric spinor charge $Q_{\alpha}$.

Has this topic been studied at all?

Answer (score 11):

I) First it should be stressed that [Noether's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) is not really about Lie groups but only about Lie algebras, i.e., one just needs $n$ *infinitesimal* symmetries to deduce $n$ conservation laws.

II) Secondly, it is straightforward to check (by recalling the proof of Noether's theorem) that Noether's theorem generalizes to [supernumber](http://planetmath.org/supernumber)-valued variables, transformations, currents, and charges.

Examples of Grassmann-odd symmetries include BRST symmetry and Poincare super-symmetry.