# Wronskian of a Harmonic oscillator

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, conservation-laws, harmonic-oscillator

Given a harmonic oscillator $\ddot{x}+\omega_0^2x=0$ if we calculate the Wronskian using [Abel's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_identity) 
we get $W[x_1,x_2](t)=W_0e^{\int_{t_0}^t 0 ds}=W_0$

which means (for our two solutions $x_1$ and $x_2$) that 
$$
det\begin{pmatrix} 
\dot{x_1} & \dot{x_2} \\
x_1 & x_2 
\end{pmatrix}=\dot{x_1}x_2-\dot{x_2}x_1=W_0$$

is some conserved quantity. To me it smells like it should be equal to something of the form $\frac{E}{m}$ (because if we multiply $\dot{x_1}x_2-\dot{x_2}x_1$ by $m$ we get something in units of energy(we don't, I made a mistake, but anyway the question makes sense). Is the conservation of the Wronskian actually the conservation of something energy-ish (to the factor of $m$) for our system or is it something else, if not what is it (physically, what is its physical meaning)?

Ps: I think it probably isn't energy (it definitely isn't energy) because in the case of parametric resonance (aka.  $\ddot{x}+\omega_0^2(t)x=0$) the Wronskian is also conserved but the Energy isn't. I might be wrong :)

pss: [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/240410/103567) answer states that the conservation of the Wronskian means the conservation od angular moment, however I find it unclear what angular momentum would mean for a 1D system

Comment: You have two solutions. Energy of *what*? It's better to think in terms of a two-dimensional system, where $W_0$ is just the angular momentum.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/240049/84967

Comment: I have two linearly independent  solutions whose linear combination $Ax_1+Bx_2$ gives us some solutions for some initial conditions, the initial conditions will also determine the Energy $E$

So Energy of what, the Energy of the system (for some particular choice of initial conditions)