# What is the physical meaning of a Supercharge?

Tags: conservation-laws, supersymmetry, noethers-theorem

What is actually being conserved?
I've calculated it for the Wess-Zumino model but I still have no idea what is actually being conserved due to Noether's Theorem.

There is already a similar question, [What conserved quantity does Supersymmetry imply?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/366833/what-conserved-quantity-does-supersymmetry-imply)
But the answers don't actually say if there is anything physically conserved.

I have heard that the number of fermions is kept equal to the number of bosons, but is this not a fact that susy *requires*? I feel like it doesn't actually come from the charge itself.

In Qmechanic's answer it is said that "the experimental consequences of a conserved supercharge are extracted by other indirect means." What are these means?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [What conserved quantity does Supersymmetry imply?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/366833/2451) and links therein.

Comment: You "feel" wrong. For a given mass, an unbroken supercharge preserves the perfect match between bosonic and fermionic d.o.f. The vanishing difference of the two is what is "physically conserved".