# What does a supercharge physically conserve?

Tags: supersymmetry, spinors, superalgebra

What is actually being conserved? I've calculated it for the Wess-Zumino model but I still have no idea what is actually being conserved due to Noether's Theorem.

There is already a [similar question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/366833/what-conserved-quantity-does-supersymmetry-imply), but the answers don't actually say if there is anything physically conserved.

I have heard that the number of fermions is kept equal to the number of bosons, but is this not a fact that susy requires? I feel like it doesn't actually come from the charge itself.

In Qmechanic's answer it is said that "the experimental consequences of a conserved supercharge are extracted by other indirect means." What are these means?

Comment: Supercharge *is* what is conserved. The question should be I guess "What does supercharge represent physically?".

Comment: It is a formal entity conserved by quantum motion. "Physically"? You mean you want an intuitive metaphor for it? You are happy with the "physical" intuition on the Runge-Lenz vector? It is all in the math, I fear. Unbroken supercharges do pair up fermions and bosons of a given mass, so you heard right. Intros to SUSY prove that at the very start.

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/479145/2451