# Why is supersymmetry a continuous symmetry?

Tags: supersymmetry, fermions, lie-algebra, grassmann-numbers, superalgebra

Supersymmetry feels like a discrete symmetry to me, since the fermions are turning into bosons, and vice versa. I understand there is an infinitesimal parameter involved in the transformations, but I don't know what it actually determines physically.

Comment: they can continuously transform into each other. E.g. pure fermion can pick up a delta that is proportional to the boson and vice versa

Comment: What does this mean physically? I mean, how can a fermion transform into some percentage of a boson?
$\phi \rightarrow \phi +\delta \phi=\phi+\bar{\epsilon}\chi$

Comment: What does it mean "physically" for a proton to transform into some percentage of a neutron?

Comment: @user45757 physics doesn't change w.r.t. such transformations, that's why it is called a symmetry (if it is unbroken of course). But requiring any symmetry puts restrictions on the action.

Answer (score 4):

1. A [super-Poincare algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-Poincar%C3%A9_algebra) is a [Lie superalgebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_superalgebra), whose elements are generators for a [Lie supergroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supergroup_(physics)), and therefore formally corresponds to a continuous symmetry.

   Of course the elephant in the room is the elusive nature of Grassmann-odd numbers, cf. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/366833/2451) related Phys.SE post and links therein.
2. A super-charge $Q$ belongs to the super-Poincare algebra and takes bosons into fermions, and vice-versa.

   Very oversimplified (i.e. ignoring the Grassmann-nature), $Q$ acts like a raising or lowering operator, which gives it a discrete feel, cf. OP's question. Think e.g. of $su(2)$-irreps with a discrete $m$ quantum number, such as in the [isospin symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isospin), which is also a continuous symmetry.