# Why was the supersymmetry super?

Tags: symmetry, supersymmetry

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersymmetry) stated that

> In a supersymmetric theory the equations for force and the equations for matter are identical.

And the supersymmetry was also stated to be the correspondence between boson and fermions being "suppersymmetric partners".

Those statement seemed to be very counter intuitive from the usual "symmetry" that one saw from CM, QM, or QFT, where it was described by generators, currents, and charges, etc.

What was the difference between supersymmetry and symmetry? and why was the supersymmetry super?

Comment: The supersymmetry algebra still has generators.

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/366833).

Comment: "Super" indicates transcendence of symmetry, which relates bosons to bosons and fermions to fermions. SUSY "rotates" fermions to bosons, which goes beyond conventional symmetry. It is described by the same framework of (super) generators, currents, and charges. The sentence you are quoting is pompous blather.