Noether's theorem for supersymmetry
I know that Noether's theorem states that all symmetries of the universe correspond to some conservation law. If supersymmetry were true, would there be a new conservation law? In other words, does Noether's theorem apply to supersymmetry? If so, what conservation law might supersymmetry map to?

Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/366833/2451
